# How to query all entities from InMemoryCache?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to query all entities from my apollo local cache (InMemoryCache) but without success.

Here is how I proceed.

```
query EntityList($limit: Int!, $offset: Int!) {
  entities(
    limit: $limit,
    offset: $offset
  ) {
    __typename
    EntityId
  }
}
```

With this query : no problem.
But later, I would like to query all entities from the cache and without any params.

```
query LocalEntityList {
  entities {
    EntityId
  }
}
```

This simple code triggers an error
`Can't find field entities on object (ROOT_QUERY)....`

From the [documentation site](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html#cacheRedirect), I understand that I need to use `cacheResolvers` options on the `InMemoryCache` object.
But there is no example without passing an id as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a `@connection` directive. This will allow you to cache your entities query without the limit/offset arguments.

```
query EntityList($limit: Int!, $offset: Int!) {
  entities (
    limit: $limit,
    offset: $offset
  ) @connection(key: "EntityList_entities") {
    __typename
    EntityId
  }
}
```

Making a successive call with the same connection should return all the entities from that key.

```
query LocalEntityList {
  entities @connection(key: "EntityList_entities") {
    EntityId
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @imranolas you put me on the right track. 

 I had to set the reguired params on my local query too and it works too with
 cache policy 

    options: {
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-only',
        variables: { offset: 0, limit: 0 }
    }